# Authenticate and embed a private Google Calender in a PHP application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-api, google-calendar-api

In my PHP application I store GoogleCalender username/password for each user in the system.
Now I want to show the Calendar belongs to the user who is logged into the system.

First thing came into my mind was use of Zend Google Calender API to get calendar data and populate them on a something like FullCalender (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

But I was wondering this is like reinventing the wheel, Is there simple way to do this? May be directly integrate Google Calendar widget?

I've seen examples for embedding  public calendars,but is it possible for private calendars and application does the authentication ?